# How to create options dialog with VbScript?

Tags: vbscript

I have a third party application that invokes a vsbscript file for certain operations.  I would like to put up a user prompt with a choice of options, either a drop down list or checkbox or some such.  However, all I can find is the input box option.

I don't think HTAs are an option in my case (unless there is a way to call them from a .vbs file?)

My other thought was some sort of ActiveX control, but I can't locate a built-in one that would be available by default on WindowsXP/Vista.

Anybody have any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Can you edit the 3rd party VBScript? If you could give us a little more detail, we might have some better options for you.

Comment: Yes, editing the vbscript is exactly what we are doing.  The 3rd party product automatically invokes it if it is present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is, you really can't. Tmdean's solution is the only way I can think of either. That said, you can spruce up the input box so it doesn't look *horrible*. Give this a run, I don't think it's an *epic* fail:

```
Dim bullet
Dim response
bullet = Chr(10) & "   " & Chr(149) & " "
Do
    response = InputBox("Please enter the number that corresponds to your selection:" & Chr(10) & bullet & "1.) Apple" & bullet & "2.) Bannana" & bullet & "3.) Pear" & Chr(10), "Select Thing")
    If response = "" Then WScript.Quit  'Detect Cancel
    If IsNumeric(response) Then Exit Do 'Detect value response.
    MsgBox "You must enter a numeric value.", 48, "Invalid Entry"
Loop
MsgBox "The user chose :" & response, 64, "Yay!"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use an hta for this it can be done like this.
The VBScript:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Run the hta.
WshShell.Run "Test.hta", 1, true
'Display the results.
MsgBox "Return Value = " & getReturn
Set WshShell = Nothing

Function getReturn
'Read the registry entry created by the hta.
On Error Resume Next
     Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    getReturn = WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment\MsgResp")
    If ERR.Number  0 Then
        'If the value does not exist return -1
         getReturn = -1
    Else
        'Otherwise return the value in the registry & delete the temperary entry.
        WshShell.RegDelete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment\MsgResp"
    End if
    Set WshShell = Nothing
End Function
```

Then design the hta as desired, and include the following methods

```
'Call this when the OK button is clicked.
Sub OK_Click
    For Each objradiobutton In Opt
         If objradiobutton.Checked Then
              WriteResponse objradiobutton.Value
        End If
    Next
    window.Close
End Sub

'Call this when the Cancel button is clicked.
Sub Cancel_Click
     WriteResponse("CANCEL")
     window.Close
End Sub

'Write the response to the registry
Sub WriteResponse(strValue)
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment\MsgResp", strValue
     Set WshShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

I used a group of radio buttons named "Opt" to make a choice, but you could use any controls you would like.
Because hta's cannot return values, this will create a temperary registry entry.  If you are not comforatable messing with the registry, you could also write the result to a temperary text file.
This approach is nice because you can design the hta any way you like, rather than using the supplied inputbox and choosing numbers (thats so DOS).
This could also be nice if you expanded the hta to create itself based on arguments passed to it, like passing in a title, a message to display, an array of options, a set of buttons.  That way you could use the same hta any time you needed to get input from the user.

Answer (score 3):

You can use DialogLib to create forms with dropdowns and checkboxes. DialogLib is still in it's ealy stages, but is's allready quite usefull: http://www.soren.schimkat.dk/Blog/?p=189

Answer (score 1):

Try [WshShell.Popup](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/wsh/17415.asp). Depending upon your data that may work for you...

Otherwise you could investigate PowerShell.

Comment: If I understand WshShell.Popup correctly, that doesn't give me the options to create my own arbitrary list, for example, "Queue1, Queue2, Queue3" etc, so I don't see that it gains me anything different than the regular input box (http://wsh2.uw.hu/ch08b.html)

Comment: You could use it repeatedly to say, would you like option 1, then would you like option 2, etc. Not ideal, but it IS a scripting language with pretty much no UI.

Comment: YOu could always use the Yes No Maybe Cancel buttons and then explain to the user that Yes mean blah, No mean yeah, Cancel means okay....etc. but really this is kind of ugly.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to script Internet Explorer. You can use VBScript to launch IE and load a local HTML file, and attach a VBScript sub to a form's submit button (or any other JavaScript events), which can then close the IE window as part of its execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch an HTA from a VBScript.

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run "Test.hta"
```

EDIT

Since you have full control of the VBScript, could you make the 3rd party VBScript simply call your HTA? You could put the UI and whatever processing code inside of the HTA.

Comment: One thing aphoria forgot to mention is that you need to include the full path of the hta file, and sometimes you need to nun "mshta.exe ____" where ____ is the path to the hta.

Comment: I would think the problem with this is not starting the hta, but getting values back from the hta.

Comment: Yes, I would need to be able to get the values back from the hta.

Comment: Downvoted because the response does not answer the question.  If the question was "how do I start an hta from VBScript" I would have upvoted.

Comment: Well, he did state that he didn't think you could start an HTA from a VBScript. My answer showed that you can. I may not have given him the complete answer he was looking for, but my answer is certainly relevant. I was surprised by the downvote because I usually only downvote answers that are totally inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

As an example of @TmDean's suggestion, there's this class that I sometimes use which scripts IE (well, it scripted IE6; I haven't tried the more recent incarnations.)

```
class IEDisplay
    '~ Based on original work by Tony Hinkle, tonyhinkle@yahoo.com

    private TEMPORARY_FOLDER

    private objShell
    private objIE
    private objFSO
    private objFolder
    private strName
    private streamOut
    private objDIV

    private numHeight
    private numWidth
    private numTop
    private numLeft

    private sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim strComputer
    Dim objWMIService
    Dim colItems
    Dim objItem
    Dim arrMonitors( 10, 1 )
    Dim numMonitorCount

    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "Select  * from Win32_DesktopMonitor")

    numMonitorCount = 0 
    For Each objItem in colItems
        arrMonitors( numMonitorCount, 0 ) = objItem.ScreenHeight
        arrMonitors( numMonitorCount, 1 ) = objItem.ScreenWidth
        numMonitorCount = numMonitorCount + 1
    Next

    numHeight = arrMonitors( 0, 0 )
    numWidth = arrMonitors( 0, 1 )

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    TEMPORARY_FOLDER = 2
    set objFolder = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder( TEMPORARY_FOLDER )
    strName = objFSO.BuildPath( objFolder, objFSO.GetTempName ) & ".html"
    WriteFileU strName, Join( Array( "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Information</TITLE></HEAD>", _
                     "<BODY SCROLL='NO'><CENTER><FONT FACE='arial black'> <HR COLOR='BLACK'>", _
                     "<DIV id='MakeMeAnObject'></DIV>", _
                     "<HR COLOR='BLACK'></FONT></CENTER></BODY></HTML>" ), vbCRLF ), WF_CREATE        
    numTop = 0
    numLeft = 0
    end sub

    Sub Init( strPosition )
    'NW, N, NE, W, CENTRE, E, SW, S, SE
    Select Case strPosition
    Case "NW"
        numTop = 0
        numLeft = 0
    Case "N"
        numTop = 0
        numLeft = ( numWidth / 2 ) - 250
    Case "NE"
        numTop = 0
        numLeft = numWidth - 500
    Case "W"
        numTop = ( numHeight / 2 ) - 55
        numLeft = 0
    Case "CENTRE"
        numTop = ( numHeight / 2 ) - 55
        numLeft = ( numWidth / 2 ) - 250
    Case "E"
        numTop = ( numHeight / 2 ) - 55
        numLeft = numWidth - 500
    Case "SW"
        numTop = numHeight - 110
        numLeft = 0
    Case "S"
        numTop = numHeight - 110
        numLeft = ( numWidth / 2 ) - 250
    Case "SE"
        numTop = numHeight - 110
        numLeft = numWidth - 500
    Case Else
        numTop = 0
        numLeft = 0
    End Select

    SetupIE( strName )
    Set objDIV = objIE.Document.All("MakeMeAnObject")
    end sub

    private sub Class_Terminate()
    'Close IE and delete the file
    objIE.Quit
    '~ optionally you may want to get rid of the temp file
    end sub

    public sub Display( strMsg, numMillisec )
    objDIV.InnerHTML = strMsg
    WScript.Sleep numMillisec
    end sub

    Private Sub SetupIE(File2Load)
     objIE.Navigate File2Load
     objIE.ToolBar = False
     objIE.StatusBar = False
     objIE.Resizable = False

     Do
     Loop While objIE.Busy

     objIE.Width = 500
     objIE.Height = 110
     objIE.Left = numLeft
     objIE.Top = numTop
     objIE.Visible = True
     objShell.AppActivate("Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    End Sub

end class
```

here is the missing (from the original posting) WriteFileU function

```
Const WF_APPEND = 1
Const WF_CREATE = 2

Const WF_FOR_APPENDING = 8
Const WF_FOR_WRITING = 2
Const WF_CREATE_NONEXISTING = True

Const CONST_READ = 1, CONST_WRITE = 2, CONST_APPEND = 8

Const AS_SYSTEMDEFAULT = -2, AS_UNICODE = -1, AS_ASCII = 0

Sub WriteFileU( sFilename, sContents, nMode )
  Dim oStream
  If nMode = WF_APPEND Then
    Set oStream = oFSO.OpenTextFile( sFilename, WF_FOR_APPENDING, WF_CREATE_NONEXISTING, AS_UNICODE )
  ElseIf nMode = WF_CREATE Then
    Set oStream = oFSO.OpenTextFile( sFilename, WF_FOR_WRITING, WF_CREATE_NONEXISTING, AS_UNICODE )
  Else
    STOP
  End If

  oStream.Write sContents
  oStream.Close
  Set oStream = Nothing
End Sub
```

and then as an example of it's use

```
set i = new IEDisplay 
a = array("NW", "N", "NE", "W", "CENTRE", "E", "SW","S","SE")
for each aa in a
    i.init aa
    i.display "Here in " & aa & " of screen", 1000
next
```

Now that's not immediately useful (especially are there are a pile of calls to my own utility routines in there) but it gives a framework. By modifying what HTML is stored, you could add support for listboxes etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is eleven years too late, but it sounds like this would be more along the lines of what the original request would be looking for:

```
Sub CustomMsgBox(msg)
Dim ie, Style, FormExit
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Navigate "about:blank"

    While ie.ReadyState <> 4: WScript.Sleep 100: Wend

    ie.Toolbar = False
    ie.StatusBar = False
    ie.Width = 450
    ie.Height = 275

    ie.document.body.innerHTML = "<title>Choose a Color</title><p class='msg'>Choose an option:</p>" & "<input type='radio' id='myRadio' name='colors' value='red'>Red</br><input type='radio' id='myRadio' name='colors' value='yellow'>Yellow</br><input type='radio' id='myRadio' name='colors' value='blue'>Blue"

    Set Style = ie.document.CreateStyleSheet
    Style.AddRule "p.msg", "font-family:calibri;font-weight:bold;"

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me in an HTA file (that I opened from VBS using WScript.Shell Run).  The trick was to get the data back to VBS which I accomplished by having HTA create an XML file that VBS read.

```
Sub CopySelect(sSrcId, sTargetId)
    Dim oTarget: Set oTarget = document.getElementById(sTargetId)
    Dim oSrc: Set oSrc = document.getElementById(sSrcId)
    Dim j, n, o

    oTarget.length = 0

    For j = 0 to oSrc.length - 1
        Set o = oSrc.options(j)
        Set n = document.createElement("option")
        n.text = o.text
        n.value = o.value
        oTarget.add n
    Next
End Sub
```